# What purpose does a for loop serve when removing an Item from a Array

Tags: java

So I have the code below and want to know what the purpose of the for loop is, since I can remove the item without needing the for loop or am I wrong?

```
public Item3 removeItem(Item3 anItem){
    Item3 temp = anItem;
    int element = locateByCat(anItem.getCat());
    for(int i = element; i < inventory.length - 1; i++){
      inventory[i] = inventory[i+1];
    }
    itemCount--;
    inventory[inventory.length-1] = new Item3();
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Well, you aren't removing an item from a list, for one thing.  You're removing an item from an array.

Comment: What happened when you tried to trace through the logic of the code a step at a time? What happened when you tried to write the code in the way that you think should work instead? What actually do you think it means to "remove" the item? At any rate, "please explain to me how someone else's code works" is not a question we can answer here, because we do not know why you don't already understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You are shifting the things inside to the left from the elements index position so that at the end is a new item but the old item is not in the array anymore. So you fill the gap and add a new Item at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate and alter linked list at the same time. You will get `ConcurrentModificationException` when you try to do the same. Here you are using array as a temporary space to hold the array elements and delete the element by skipping it.

Hope it answers your question.